# Image src is changing but the image is not updating in Internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code

```js
$('.thumb-container-xs').click(function() {
  ///alert("You have clicked!");
  var img = $(this).find('img');
  var img_src = img.attr('src');
  var img_title = img.attr('title');
  var img_alt = img.attr('alt');

  $("#productImage0").attr({
    src: img_src + '?' + new Date().getTime(), //adding random number at the end of the src not working
    title: img_title,
    alt: img_alt
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 thumb-container clearfix" id="activeProductImgContainer">
  <!--Big Image-->
  <a href="#" class="img-bg" id="activeProductImgBg">
    <img src="http://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stocksnap.jpg" class="thumb-img img-thumbnail thumb-custom" id="productImage0" alt="Mypic" title="My pic">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
  <!---small images-->
  <div class=" col-xs-3 thumb-container-xs">
    <a class="img-bg-xs" id="productImage2" href="#"><img class="thumb-img-xs  img-responsive thumb-custom" src="http://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stocksnap.jpg" title="f" alt="f"></a>
  </div>
  <div class=" col-xs-3 thumb-container-xs">
    <a class="img-bg-xs" id="productImage3" href="#"><img class="thumb-img-xs  img-responsive thumb-custom" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.spl/1353_bof.jpg" title="g" alt="h"></a>
  </div>
  <div class=" col-xs-3 thumb-container-xs">
    <a class="img-bg-xs" id="productImage4" href="#"><img class="thumb-img-xs  img-responsive thumb-custom" src="https://www.bensound.com/bensound-img/betterdays.jpg" title="h" alt="h"></a>
  </div>
  <div class=" col-xs-3 thumb-container-xs">
    <a class="img-bg-xs" id="productImage5" href="#"><img class="thumb-img-xs  img-responsive thumb-custom" src="https://www.bensound.com/bensound-img/littleplanet.jpg" title="i" alt="i"></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

What the code actually does is update the big image whenever i click on a small image thumbnail.
Everything is working fine in Crome and firefox but not working in Internet Explorer. When I'm clicking on the small image thumbnail the 'src' of the image is changing but the image is not updating. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Make this as one snippet

Comment: Probably answer is here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e3c16797-83e7-46b1-a157-f8454aea5e47/images-are-not-printing-in-ie9-with-img-srchttps-jpg-?forum=ieitprocurrentver

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a typo in your snippet or not, but `#productImage1` is not in your markup. You go from `productImage0` to `productImage2`.

Comment: Wold be better if you put in the web hosted images in example. Now it looks like everything is good since URLs and text change like they should.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.No problem with my code.As internet explorer does not support `object-fit` css property,I had to hide the `<img>` tag and set a `background-image` property to it's parent which is `#activeProductImgBg` and what I did just changed the image `src` which is hidden in IE.But I had to change the background property of it's parent also at the same time.Now it's working fine.
Here is the additional code

```js
 $("#activeProductImgBg").css('background-image', 'url(' + img_src + ')');
```

Comment: Nice, you found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code instead of yours and see if load() triggers. They claim with URLs fix you did (adding a seed in the end) it should work. I just don't have IE11 installed to test it out.

```
$('.thumb-container-xs').click(function() {
      ///alert("You have clicked!");
      var img = $(this).find('img');
      var img_src = img.attr('src');
      var img_title = img.attr('title');
      var img_alt = img.attr('alt');

      $("#productImage0").attr({
        src: img_src + '?' + new Date().getTime(), //adding random number at the end of the src not working
        title: img_title,
        alt: img_alt
      });
      $("#productImage1").attr({
        src: img_src + '?' + new Date().getTime(), //adding random number at the end of the src not working
        title: img_title,
        alt: img_alt
      });

      $("#productImage0").load(function(){console.log(0)});
      $("#productImage1").load(function(){console.log(1)});

    });
```

If the images are not loaded console.logs will not fire, if they do then is a matter of refreshing the DOM.

This trick worked for me to force the browser to redraw the element, you hide show their parent in quick succession.

```
$('#activeProductImgContainer').hide().show(0);
```

Comment: Thank you @DanteTheSmith. Few things I want to mention- as I am using jquery 3,` load()` function is deprecated. Instead I had  tried with `on('load',function(....` and it fired the `console.log()` but still no luck in internet explorer. I tried the hide and show trick but did not work. The first image got stuck although `src` is changing. May be something to do with the browser cache.

Comment: That were the things that came to mind and I don't have IE11 on this machine to test it out. I had problems with IE before with refreshing and the later trick worked so far. Sorry it didn't help.